# Finding all possible Combinations of 4 Vectors with C++

Tags: c++, combinations

I want to find all possible combinations of four basis vectors (dimension = 4), depending on the user input. Repetition should be allowed.

I.e. lets call the vectors a, b, c and d.

If the User enters N=3, the combinations can be:

aaa
aab
aac
.
.
.
ddd

I tried my best, but I am not this familiar to C++ yet.

The application should also compute the multiplication of the basis vectors (i.e. a*a*a) and store the result.

I surely took a a look in the forum before, but found articles about combining integers or elements of vectors only.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Lets see your existing code.  Let us know where you got stuck

Comment: Coding without User Input was easy, just as many for-loops, as I want to have. But if I don't know, how many for-loops will be needed in advance, I don't know where to start.

Comment: this is homework, right?

Comment: @Kepler: does recursion ring a bell?

Comment: I have to do it for my studies. I know what recursion is, but I am not able yet to find a recursion by myself. Iteration is the key :-) But if you have a recursive way, its okay.

Comment: recursion is the key. you can maintain the state in a stack but that will just complicate the code.

Answer (score 1):

If your program is linux based (e.g. you have access to a bash-type shell), then you can get all of the combinations of say a,b,c,d with N=3 by typing out the command: "echo {a,b,c,d}{a,b,c,d}{a,b,c,d}" - which will print out all the combinations above: aaa, aab... etc.

Then you could catch that output and parse it letter-by-letter and multiply a base vector (say (1,1,1,1) for dim = 4) by each of the vectors corresponding to the letter. But then again, what do you mean by multiply the vectors? You mean find the magnitude of a*a*a? Because you can't multiply (1x4) vectors together - you can only take their dot product. (so the only possible interpretation of a*a*a would seem to be |a|^3.)

Example of invoking echo command:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int n; //user given - n>1
Vector4D* vectors[n]; // Or some other name for the class
// Have the user input the vectors
std::string base = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z";
std::string list = "{"+base.substr(0,2*n+1)+"}";
std::string query = "echo ";
for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
    query += list;
}
File *file;
file=popen(query.c_string(), "r");
char combo[4];
std::vector<Vector4D> results;
while(fscanf(file,"%s", combo)){
    Vector4D result(1,1,1,1); //our default (identity) vector
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
        result = Vector4D.multiply(result, Vectors[combo[i]-'a']);
    }
    results.push_back(result);
} 
fclose(file);
```

something like this, though a) untested b) incomplete c) only works for sample sizes of up to 26 vectors (well 52 if you include the capitals)

Comment: does cross product ring a bell?

Comment: I've never heard of people referring to cross product as multiplication. Beats me why anyone would. Also, in the example case, a cross a would yield 0, so that seems a bit unnecessary. And a cross 0 doesn't even make sense. Numerically it is also zero, but visually, it doesn't seem to have a meaning.

Comment: @strelok: Because product is a synonym for multiplication.  ["In mathematics, a product is the result of multiplying"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_%28mathematics%29)...

Comment: what I really have to do is computing the tensor product, but when I have the combinations, that should be no problem

Comment: @strelok: cross product of colinear vectors does make sense. take an example from physics where you calculate the force on a moving charge in a magnetic field. if the vectors are aligned there is no force. also note that a*a*a.. is just one from all the combinations.

Comment: I never said A cross A didn't make sense - I said A crossed with the 0 vector would not make sense / be useful. And about OpenSUSE... it should work - you must have a form of the echo command on it...

Comment: Yes, you can build the query from within C++, and then fetch the output using the popen() command - docs are: http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_popen.htm

Comment: A crossed with 0 vector, again, does make sense. take the same example.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using a multi-dimensional array (in this case, a 2-dimensional array).

Now, my level of programming is not so good either, so my programs tend to be a tad clunky, but hopefully you can get an idea of what i am talking about in the pseudo code example below!

base the count of the nest on the number input by the user:

```
user enters 4

array{ar1{a,b,c,d},ar2{a,b,c,d},ar3{a,b,c,d}ar4{a,b,c,d}}
create counter var for each array (c1, c2, c3, c4)

loop increment counters c1-4 for each letter (a-b)
print value from array table.
```

I know its pretty sloppy, but its the best I can come up with off the top of my head (haven't programmed in nearly 3 years! LOL) but definitely look into the multi-dimensional arrays:

http://www.tenouk.com/clabworksheet/labworksheet10.html

good luck!

Comment: What do you mean with: "loop increment counters c1-4 for each letter (a-b) ?"

Comment: @Kepler - you create a counter for each array (aka, C1-C4) and use each counter to step into each sublet of the array. (use the counter to increment / reset A through D). take a look at the link I provided for more information on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

As this is homework, I won't write you a complete solution. Check this pseudocode:

```
all(&srcvectors, depth, temp, &resultvectors)
    if (depth == 0)
        resultvectors.push(temp);
    else
        for (int i=0; i < 4; i++)
            all(srcvectors, depth-1, crossproduct(temp, srcvectors[i]), resultvectors);
```

You have to call this from an outer for loop, passing each srcvector as temp. You also have to figure out what the initial depth you have to pass (try to reason about it, and do not use trial and error).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

put on two for loops that are 4 by 4.
That will run though every single possible combination.

```
vector<char> temp;


temp.push_back('a');
temp.push_back('b');
temp.push_back('c');
temp.push_back('d');



for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        cout << temp[i] << temp[k] << endl;
}
```

Add more for loops for longer length. Right now it does only 2 output combinations at a time.

For example:

```
vector<char> temp;


temp.push_back('a');
temp.push_back('b');
temp.push_back('c');
temp.push_back('d');


for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        {
            cout << temp[j] << temp[i] << temp[k] << endl;
            Sleep(25);
        }
    }
}

system("PAUSE");
```

this would output every possible combination up to a length of 3.
Anything more and you would want a recursive function.

Comment: **Moderator Note** _The comments under this post have been removed because the conversation degenerated into far more noise than signal. Please keep comments polite, constructive and on topic_.